# Is Serre's $S_1$ condition equivalent to having no embedded primes?

Tags: commutative-algebra

Today I tried to prove that if a Noetherian ring $A$ satisfies Serre's $R_0$ and $S_1$ conditions, then $A$ is reduced. Now we recall that $R_0$ means the localization at any minimal prime is a field (Nakayama's lemma) and $S_1$ means that $\operatorname{depth} A_{\mathfrak{p}} \geq \min\{ 1, \dim A_{\mathfrak{p}}\}$.

> Is it true that the $S_1$ condition is **equivalent** to saying that $A$ has no embedded primes, i.e. every associated prime is minimal?

If this is true, then it would allow us to give the following quick proof that $R_0 + S_1 \implies$ reduced:

We know $A$ [injects](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1085752) into the product $\prod_{\mathfrak{p} \in \operatorname{Ass} A} A_{\mathfrak{p}}$. However, every associated prime is minimal and the localization at a minimal prime is field. It follows $A$ injects into a finite direct product of fields and thus is  reduced.

Comment: This is Tag [031Q](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/031Q).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, $S_1$ is equivalent to saying that every associated prime is minimal for Noetherian rings. This follows directly from the following facts:

i) $\text{Ass}(S^{-1}A) = \text{Ass}(A) \cap \text{Spec}(S^{-1}A)$. In particular $p \in \text{Ass}(A) \iff pA_p \in \text{Ass}(A_p)$.
ii) if $(A,m)$ is local, then $\text{depth}(A) = 0$ iff $m \in \text{Ass}(A)$. In particular $pA_p \in \text{Ass}(A_p) \iff \text{depth}(A_p) = 0$.

Thus, if $A$ is $S_1$, then for any associated prime $p$, $0 = \text{depth}(A_p) \ge \min(1, \dim A_p) \implies \dim A_p = 0$, so $p$ is minimal. For the converse, if $p$ is nonminimal, then $p$ is not associated, so $\text{depth}(A_p) \ge 1$, hence $A$ is $S_1$.